# Fetched values from Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I try to fetch specific values from remote config in Firebase, but it always gives me the value that I defined in client side the first time.

Here is my code:

```
 public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;
private static final String FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY ="friendly_msg_length";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
    FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);

    Map<String, Object> defaultConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
    defaultConfigMap.put(FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY, DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT);
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultConfigMap);
    fetchCnfig();
}

private void fetchCnfig() {
    long cacheExpiration = 3600;
    if(mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getInfo().getConfigSettings().isDeveloperModeEnabled()){
        cacheExpiration = 0;
    }
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                        applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
                    }else{
                        Log.w(TAG, "error fetching config" + task.getException().getMessage());
                        applyRetrievedLengthLimit();
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void applyRetrievedLengthLimit() {
    long friendly_msg_length = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getLong(FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY);
    mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(((int) friendly_msg_length))});
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong would be evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bug was that I put FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH_KEY value at firebase project and I had to put the value of this property (friendly_msg_length in my case)

Hope it can help for everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

After updating value you need to **Publish changes** from firebase console

[image]

After the changes are published, it will be available to end users and you can fetch that value in application.

Comment: This was done but still doesn't change the values received from the firebase